# Guess the song and artist (2)

Tags: music

$$\lfloor \nabla_{\mu} X_{\nu} + \nabla_{\nu} X_{\mu}\rfloor = 0$$

> **Hint1:** Also a video game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> Killing Floor by Howlin Wolf?
>
>  $\nabla_{\mu} X_{\nu} + \nabla_{\nu} X_{\mu} = 0$ is the "Killing equation", and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor function

Comment: that was quick! (Not quite as cryptic as the first question, but just for fun!) - link between the two questions was going to be the next hint :)

Comment: @martin I think I managed to catch this while it was up earlier today, started trying to figure it out then.

Comment: early start! ... Hendrix did a cover of course ;)